# PHP SharePoint API Document Subdirectory Listings

Tags: php, sharepoint

I've just implemented the SharePointAPI for PHP which can be found https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API

I was able to retrieve all of the SharePoint Lists from the WSDL, and was able to use the ->read($list) function to retrieve a List which holds Document folders and files.

Within the list, if the item is a file, I'm able to download it fine.
However, if the item is another folder (a subdirectory), how do I access that directory's folders and files?

The ->read($list) function doesn't work, and I'm kind of at a loss. Does anybody know how I can read a List item's folders and files as it were a List?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although part of me suspects you are probably the person who ended up  managing to answer their own question over on the github issues; I thought I may as well repost that answer here in case others have the same problem.

Essentially (although its a bit of a work around) you can get a listing of the contents of a folder in a sharepoint list, by calling the following method:

```
$sp->read($listName,
          NULL,//$limit 
          NULL,//$query
          NULL,//$view 
          NULL,//$sort 
          "<Folder>" . $listName . "\\" . $folderName . "</Folder>"//$options 
)
```

Hopefully once manage to find a bit of spare time, I'll add a dedciated method for doing this to the library, just to make it a little more straight forward in future.